# Spanish Brigs aren't fake?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

While looking at some screenshots from Sid Meier's Pirates! I came across this one:

[image]

I claim that Guilo did a good job of Photoshoping Spanish flags on a Brig. However a friend of mine said that they were extremely rare to find. However he doesn't beleive the amount of gold.

So are these Spanish Brigs real? Or is this just a hoax?

Comment: @YoungGuilo This might be your picture. Is it real?

Comment: I've never seen that much gold in a plunder before, even the treasure fleets never carried that much.

Comment: @spartacus Actually the largest haul of gold I ever took was 72700 from Blackbeard. I just thought of a new question!

Comment: yes, pirates can give you that much gold if you leave them along for a long time while they amass their treasure.  I specifically said I've never seen treasure fleets carry that much.

Comment: @PeterV. can you please give me some feedback on my answer? If it helped you maybe consider accepting it :)

Comment: I've gotten over 100k gold from a single ship before -- just once I recall, I immediately went to the nearest port and divided the plunder though. I have no idea what the circumstances are around how a ship gets that much gold, it's possible it was a treasure fleet though.

Answer (score 2):

> The Brig is fairly uncommon in the Caribbean. All nations use Brigs as
>   Raiders, to attack enemy shipping and Ports. However in this role, it
>   is a little less likely to spot a Brig rather than, say, a Frigate.
>
> More commonly, players involving themselves in Missions received from
>   Settlements, Indian Villages and Jesuit Missions will encounter Brigs
>   more often, as these are usually sent as Privateers on most Difficulty
>   settings.
>
> Finally, the Famous Pirate Jean Lafitte sails a heavily-upgraded Brig.

So basically I think that is photoshopped. No way that amount of gold and a spanish brig.

More info [here](http://sidmeierspirates.wikia.com/wiki/Brig)!